# Share a Google document with a preset group / team, rather than 1 by 1

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive

We have a team of 10 people who all use Google Drive. we share documents between us but sometimes we forget to add everyone to the document so when someone clicks through a link they will need to request access which in turn stops their workflow whilst they try and contact the owner to add them, etc.

Is there a way 'round this by setting up a group / team and adding the entire group / team in one go? Perhaps by setting up a contact in Google Contacts with multiple people attached to it?

There is a mixture of Google Apps for Business users, Google Apps for Business users in a separate company, and free personal Google Drive users that would need to be in this group / team.

Comment: You could use a google group to share a file or folder. Another alternative is to use a Google Team Drive

Comment: @Rubén - i had a quick read up on google groups and found this : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!homeredir - is that what you where reffering to ? It seems to be about creating a kind of online private forum. From what i can see we wouldnt be able to use team drives as we have a a mixture of Google Apps for Business users, Google Apps for Business users in a separate company, and free personal Google Drive users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive allow to share files with specific people by adding their email address or by adding the email address of a Google Group.

If you have a G-Suite account, another alternative could be to use Google Team Drive. This could be possible if Team Drive is enabled for your organization and if Google Drive for your organization is configured to allow to share files and folders with users that don't belong to the organization.

From [Requirements to manage Team Drives](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en)

> G Suite editions
>
> This feature is available with the G Suite Enterprise or Business or
> Education edition. If your domain has a mix of G Suite Enterprise /
> Business and G Suite Basic users, the G Suite Basic users can only
> have view access to Team Drives in your domain. They may, however, be
> granted edit access to individual files within a Team Drive.

References

- [Share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?hl=en)
- [Manage Team Drives](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en)